# iphone apps page like feature using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am a newbie to iOS app development, I am trying to create an iPhone apps home page like feature where different apps can be listed in grid view, can have multiple pages, scrolling and rearranging icons in gridview. I tried using `UIScrollView` and `UICollectionView` in it.

Here is what I tried, I know its not perfect

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate  {

   let scrollView = UIScrollView()
   var frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:0, height:0)
   var pageControl : UIPageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x:50, y:300, width:200, height:50))

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.frame = self.view.frame
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .gray
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)       

    configurePageControl()

    for index in 0..<4 {
      frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
      frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size
      let grid = getcollectionview()

      let subView = UIView(frame: frame)
      subView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
      subView.addSubview(grid)
      self.view.addSubview(self.pageControl)

      self.view.addSubview(self.pageControl)
      self.scrollView.addSubview(subView)            
   }        
   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(count), height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
 }  

 func configurePageControl(count: Int) {
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 4
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.red
    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.green

}

func changePage(sender: AnyObject) -> () {     
    let x = CGFloat(pageControl.currentPage) * scrollView.frame.size.width
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x, y: 0), animated: true)
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}

func getcollectionview() -> UICollectionView {
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: 30 , bottom: 30, right: 30)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 30
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

    let myCollectionView:UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.scrollView.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    myCollectionView.dataSource = self
    myCollectionView.delegate = self
    myCollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
    myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    myCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    myCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    myCollectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
   return myCollectionView
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 50
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)            
    myCell.contentView.addSubview(label)
    myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return myCell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    print("User tapped on item \(indexPath.row)")
 } 
}
```

But this code creates multiple grid views as I am calling collectionview function in for loop. I want some elements of grid view to be created in one page and once the screen is full, rest of the elements should dynamically go to another page. I should also be able to rearrange those elements.

How can it be done? Thank you for any help

Comment: use UICollectionView with pagingEnabled set to true, no need of scrollview, pageViewController and multiple collection views

Comment: @raki , but it wont give screen to screen scrolling feel, it stops at the half of next element. I want it to be like page scroll feel. Just like the installed apps are displayed in home screen of iphone

Comment: it may help https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-springboard-like-layout-with-the-uicollectionview-class--mobile-13426